# Полноценное JavaEE приложение с клиентской частью на JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, desktop

Интересует вопрос: возможна ли реализация полноценного JavaEE приложения с клиентской частью на JavaFX? 
Просто необходимо реализовать desktop-приложение для пользователей, и что бы все операции (добавление, изменение, удаление, и т.д.) выполнялись на удаленном сервере. Единственное, что первым приходит на ум - клиентская часть на JavaFX, а серверная - на каком-нибудь сервере приложений. 
И вот очень интересна данная тема. Быть может кто-то сталкивался с данной работой, или работает; подскажите новичку. Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 2):

Возможна и нередко используется. Для этого есть [Application Client Container](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beaku.html). С помощью него можно, например, внедрить в своё десктопное приложение ссылку на EJB, и все обращение к нему будут прозрачно преобразовываться в RMI-запросы.

```
public class FXMLExampleController {
    @FXML private Text actiontarget;
    @EJB  private static Dummy dummy;

    @FXML protected void handleSubmitButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        actiontarget.setText(dummy.saySomething("Hello!"));
    }
}
```